# Insert into Input field in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

[image: sample]

I can able to find element using id but unable to use sendKeys function to insert value? expert help is needed

Comment: what is the site url? Are you able to insert manually using key board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `xpath` as:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control date-type']")).sendKeys("06/24/2017");
```

> or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='mm/dd/yyyy']")).sendKeys("06/24/2017");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It actually works perfectly, I have also did more customization of my xpath (relative xpath), they are working fine.

Comment: @AbdullahFaruk Glad to be able to help you !!! Upvote the Answer if it was helpful to you. Thanks